# Is there a way to prevent deploying .NET CF files to the target device by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, windows-embedded-compact

Microsoft considers some Visual Studio (2008 in this case) project settings to be user-specific and stores them in the project's .csproj.user file.   One of these values is the indicator that tells the IDE whether or not to deploy the .NET CF files to the target device, and the value in the file is the *NETCFDeploy* tag.  Since these projects are used by multiple developers, we want to set this value false in all cases.  We ensure that the appropriate files are built into our device's OS image, and deploying them is not only a waste of time but could also introduce differences that could mask problems in the production environment.

Is there another way of defaulting this setting to false for the affected projects so that we do not have to add all projects' .csproj.user files to source control?  If we do not add these files, we have to modify each project's value manually every time the projects are fetched from source control.  If we do add these files, they will invariably show up as modified in source control for all users since this is not the only value they contain, and that will invariably lead to files inadvertently checked in to source control that would impact other developers and later have to be rolled back.

Comment: Perhaps a workaround is to check in the .csproj.user file, then lock that file so edits cannot be checked in?